# Gravity and the $4^{th}$ dimension

Tags: geometry

If you have seen the movie Flatland, then you will understand this:

in the 2D world, 'A square', along with every-poly else (I guess that's how you'd say it) do not experience gravity. this is why 'A square' starts collapsing after a while in 3D. 
This gave me a thought, based on this fact: in 3D, and on a planet, gravity pulls toward a single point. In 4D, will being on a planet pull you toward a line of gravity? I'm looking at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFW769hqa1U#t=68.413542) sphere animation, and the epicenters of all the circles forms either a point or a line, backing up my assumption. But is it actually true?  Also, if a 3D being is standing on a 4D planet, will he be spaghettified by the odd gravity?

Comment: Well I think the physics part of this is that mass attracts, so you'd need to take that to the 4th dimension; I'm going to guess that just works like "Hypermass attracts" so that it's still a point (the center of mass of the object). Also, I wouldn't take the movie flatland and believe that to be how a 2D world would work

Comment: In a 4D world, you might expect gravity to obey an inverse cube law.  If so, there would be no stable orbits.